# How do I choose a default program to open one/more specific file(name)s?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management, file-association

I want to open specific files using different apps. But when it comes to editing different images, emulating ROMS, or opening different documents, there are special cases in which I have to use a different app for it, due to

- conflicts with compatibility
- method of producing a new image out of the existing PNG into a different proprietary filetype for the app itself (i.e. the paint app I use uses a file type for special/layered images, like .rli, .ase or .pdn), or
- different features that the other app doesn't have
  Because of this, I have to right-click the file to select which program I want to open this one .png file out of the other 199 or so .pngs I have (or more than that); the specific filename or filenames I choose to open an app with.

For example, I have A.png, B.png, C.png, or D.png. I want to open B.png with Paint.net by default, but keep A.png and C.png openable with Aseprite (as already set-by-default). Maybe I want D.png to open with RealWorld Paint as default.

If there is a way, how do I do this?

Comment: I believe, with windows, the "default app" is configurable per file extension, not filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default application on Windows is configured by file extension.

If it works for you, one way is to rename those files to say `*.pngx` and associate that extension with your second program.

Comment: Creative ;)   I like it.

Comment: Pretty creative! I see how it works, and it's flexible to work around with. Thanks!